Two mirrored screens: one has the wrong resolution, not framing all the image of the desktop
I'm on Ubuntu studio, and I have two display monitors connected through HDMI from my small computer that has two HDMI output connections. These two monitors have two different max resolutions: one is 2560x1440 and the other is 1920x1080.
When I mirror them, one of them (the one with the lower resolution at 1920x1080) won't frame the whole picture of the desktop, it will have the borders cut out, like if it was displaying a magnified portion of the screen.
I tried many settings, but I can't seem to find a solution for perfectly mirroring the two screens, so that they will both frame everything in the desktop and let me see the whole picture.
If I lower the resolution of the first monitor (the one with 2560x1440), then the same thing happens and I won't see the whole picture, everything will be magnified with borders cut out.
I should connect two monitors with identical resolution I suppose, but my 1920x1080 TV is very nice, big and expensive and I can't replace it.
How can I resolve this stupid problem?
How can I set Ubuntu so that it lets me see the same whole image of the desktop from both screens even if they have different resolutions? Is there a software that lets me fix this issue?
Please help if you know.
